# Migrate custom content type from D6 to D7

Tags: migrations

I started with the **migrate_D2D** module after did try with **migrate** 2.5. Same issue for me: Import custom content type into a fresh install of D7.

- Do I create custom content type first on the D7 intall? Is there no way to import it via d2d?
- Do I create custom CCK field into D7 db before mapping field using: 
  `$query->addField('??','field_D6customCCKfield');
  or just`
  `$this->addFieldMapping('field_D7name', 'field_D6customCCKfield');` is enought ?
- Do I map subfield like field_D6customCCKfield:data?

OK, it's better but my custom fields aren't created and I get this:

> "field_fichier_joint_lycee" was used as destination field in "field_fichier_joint_lycee" mapping but is not in list of destination fields
>   "field_lien_page_lycee" was used as destination field in "field_lien_page_lycee" mapping but is not in list of destination fields

In my class do I add this?

```
$query->addField('??','field_D6customCCKfield')
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to create the destination content type on the D7 site. Migrate/Migrate D2D won't handle that for you.

In your migration class you then use:

```
$this->addFieldMapping(destinationfield, sourcefield);
```

If you extend the D2D node migration class (DrupalNode6Migration) then you don't need to worry about defining a query.